# Full measure properties for Zariski open subsets in $p$-adic situation

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-analysis, local-fields

Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field and let $X$ be a smooth integral variety over $F$ (I am chiefly interested in the case when $X$ is a connected reductive group over $F$). Let $U$ be a non-empty open subset of $X$ with complement $Z$.

We can endow $X(F)$ with the Serre–Oesterlé measure (e.g., as in [1, Section 2.2] or [2, Section 7.4])—this is just the standard measure coming from a top form of $X$).

My question is then whether one knows a simple proof/reference for the following:

> **Claim:** The subset $Z(F)$ of $X(F)$ has measure zero.

I think this is proven in [1, Lemma 2.14]—but this is concerned with a more specific context which makes it non-ideal as a reference.

Any help is appreciated!

[1] [Magni - $p$-adic integration and birational Calabi–Yau varieties](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/Magni.pdf).

[2] Igusa, J.I., 2007. [An introduction to the theory of local zeta functions](http://www.ams.org/books/amsip/014) (Vol. 14). American Mathematical Soc.

Comment: The simplest way I know of is to use charts to reduce to the case when $X$ is an affine space, then use induction. But perhaps there is a more canonical proof.

Comment: @WSL I guess this is essentially the proof in the linked article [1] but, again, it's obfuscated by the particular context it's discussing the result in. Do you know a reference for this proof?

Comment: A terrible way to argue in the specific case when $X$ is a group is to take $d$ to be the minimal dimension of a Zariski-closed subset with non-zero measure and for an irreducible $Z$ of such dimension consider the union of $>\mu(X(F))/\mu(Z(F))$ pairwise distinct translates of $Z$. By the definition of $d$ all intersections between different translates have measure zero, so this union ought to have measure $>\mu(X(F))$ by the inclusion-exclusion formula, which is absurd.

Comment: @SashaP, why can you assume $\mu(X(F))<\infty$? Alex Youcis, i don’t know a reference where this is spelled out but I’ll try to write it up unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: @WSL Yes, I wasn't completely careful, to account for that issue let's instead run the above argument with $g^{-1}(Z(F)\cap gU)$ and $U$ in place of $Z(F)$ and $X(F)$ where $U$ is a compact open subgroup of $X(F)$ and $g$ is an arbitrary element. The result for $Z(F)$ will follow as this set is the union of $g^{-1}(Z(F)\cap gU)$ as $g$ runs over coset representatives of $U$ in $X(F)$.

Comment: If $X$ is a $\sigma$-compact $p$-adic analytic manifold, there is a well-defined notion of measure zero subsets (as the measure inherited from charts is unique up to equivalence), and if $Y$ is the zero set of an analytic map (= locally sum of its Taylor expansion) and $Y$ has empty interior, I guess it should have measure zero.

Comment: @SashaP Thanks for your suggestion. For my own sake I'd prefer to have a proof that works for general $X$, just because I do occasionally also use it in that case (even though, as I said, my main interest is groups). Still, if you want to write this as an answer, it might be useful to some readers and I'll accept it if someone else doesn't provide the full answer.

Comment: @WSL Yeah, if you'd be willing to write a fairly precise answer that would be much appreciated. Of course, I'd be very happy to save you the hassle if you just knew a reference. Thanks!

Comment: I remember working on this for my PhD thesis. I regret to say that I managed to write the proof up in such a way that the main technical difficulty was hidden in a plausible-looking sentence. But the main idea I had was using the implicit function theorem for smooth morphisms (such as $X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ where $k$ is a local field): for smooth varieties $X$, for every point $x \in X(k)$ there are functions $g_1,\ldots,g_d \in k(X)$ with $d = \dim X$ such that the map $X(k) \rightarrow k^d$ given by $x \mapsto (g_1(x),\ldots,g_d(x))$ is a local homeomorphism.

Comment: What I call the implicit function theorem here can be seen as the conjunction of a structure theorem for smooth morphisms (such as described here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/039P) with the fact that etale morphisms are local homeomorphisms when evaluated on points over local fields. Perhaps this idea allows you to reduce to the affine case, as @WSL suggested, because under the identification mentioned the subvariety $Z$ is identified with an algebraic subvariety of $k^d$.

Comment: @RP_ Thanks for your input. This is essentially the idea I think in the above linked article--using the definition of smoothness you mentioned is how you get 'charts' on the $p$-adic manifold $X(F)$, but I just don't want to include this in the article I'm writing so just want a reference and don't want to have to reproduce a proof. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm really sorry to ask a foolish question.  Why doesn't your $Z$ directly satisfy the conditions of [1, Lemma 2.14], so that you can simply cite it directly?

Comment: @LSpice Hey Loren. It's because he's starting with a smooth model over $\mathcal{O}_K$ and that $Z$ also has a smooth model over $\mathcal{O}_K$. If you look at his proof I don't really think this gets used, and it does show my desired claim. But, because he technically starts with those assumptions it's a pretty non-canonical reference for a beginner. I was hopting there was just some fairly basic reference to this result (e.g. it's sketched in a paper of Harish-Chandra) or that someone could give a comprehensive proof here that I could reference/copy. This is for a set of notes I'm writing.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364618/full-measure-properties-for-zariski-open-subsets-in-p-adic-situation#comment920897_364618)!  Have you looked at any of the work of Denef and Loeser?  I went hunting and couldn't find it, but it seems like they must need exactly this sort of result for their theory of motivic integration.

Comment: @LSpice Yeah, I spent hours trawling though Denef, Loeser, Clucker, etc. I know it's buried in there morally but I can't find an exact statement. I need it in a more general context, but certainly Harish-Chandra et. al need it for the full-measure of G^reg(F), so I imagine they must also write it down somehwere. Thanks again!